# How to fix the following issue writing a dictionary into a csv?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dictionary, anaconda

Hello I am working with sklearn and using kmeans for natural language processing, I used Kmeans to create clusters from comments, then I create a dictionary with the number of cluster as a Key and the list of comments associated as values as follows:

```
dict_clusters = {}
for i in range(0,len(kmeans.labels_)):
    #print(kmeans.labels_[i])
    #print(listComments[i])
    if not kmeans.labels_[i] in dict_clusters:
        dict_clusters[kmeans.labels_[i]] = []
    dict_clusters[kmeans.labels_[i]].append(listComments[i])
print("dictionary constructed")
```

I would like to write a csv with this dictionary I tried:

```
Out = open("dictionary.csv", "wb")
w = csv.DictWriter(Out,dict_clusters.keys())
w.writerows(dict_clusters)
Out.close()
```

however I am not sure why is wrong since I am getting the following error, besides I am not sure if this error is related with numpy since kmeans.labels_ contains several values,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CleanFile.py", line 133, in <module>
    w.writerows(dict_clusters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 156, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 146, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

I would like to appreciate support with this, I wish to get a csv with my dictionary as follows:

```
key1, value
key2, value
.
.
.
keyN, value
```

After feedback from here I tried:

```
with open("dictionary.csv", mode="wb") as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, headers=dict_clusters.keys())
    writer.writerow(dict_clusters)
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CleanFile.py", line 129, in <module>
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, headers=dict_clusters.keys())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fieldnames'
```

attempt2:

```
Out = open("dictionary.csv", "wb")
w = csv.DictWriter(Out,dict_clusters.keys())
w.writerows([dict_clusters])
Out.close()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CleanFile.py", line 130, in <module>
    w.writerows([dict_clusters])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 156, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

attempt3, this attempt takes a lot of time computing the output:

```
Out = open("dictionary.csv", "wb")
w = csv.DictWriter(Out,dict_clusters.keys())
w.writerow(dict_clusters)
Out.close()
```

the version of python that I am using is the following:

```
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
3.5.2
```

After trying a lot of times I decided to use a better way to build my dictionary as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
pairs = zip(y_pred, listComments)

dict_clusters2 = defaultdict(list)

for num, comment in pairs:
    dict_clusters2[num].append(comment)
```

However it seems that some character is making fail the creation of the csv file as follows:

```
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in dict_clusters2.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CleanFile.py", line 146, in <module>
    writer.writerow([key, value])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f609' in position 6056: character maps to <undefined>
```

In order to be more clear I performed:

```
for k,v in dict_clusters2.items():
    print(k, v)
```

And I got something like:

```
1 ['hello this is','the car is red',....'performing test']
2 ['we already have','another comment',...'strings strings']
.
.
19 ['we have',' comment music',...'strings strings dance']
```

My dictionary has a key and a list of several comments I would like to have a csv as follows:

```
1,'hello this is','the car is red',....'performing test'
2,'we already have','another comment',...'strings strings'
.
.
19,'we have',' comment music',...'strings strings dance'
```

however seems that some character is not well maped and everything fails, I would like to receive support thanks for the support.

Comment: unrelated to question: you may want to look into [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) the first code block could be written something like `for i, label in enumerate(kmeans.labels_): dict_clusters.setdefault(label, []).append(listComments[i])` (although preferably split into a few lines)

Comment: Even better than `enumerate`, in this case you might want to check out [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to loop over `listComments` and `kmeans.labels_` at the same time. More info on looping with indexes: http://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/

Comment: As an alternative to `dict.setdefault`, [collections.defaultdict(list)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) could be used. I usually prefer `defaultdict` over `dict.setdefault`, but they both achieve the same end.

Comment: you opened the file for writing in bytes `"wb"` but csv module is trying to write a string, so just change it to `"w"`

Comment: wait.. I think you are putting your data in the wrong format for `csv.DictWriter`, could you provide a (small) basic example of what the data you start with would look like and how the csv should look as output? I think you need to make a list of dictionaries where each value is for one row instead of a dictionary with lists for each column.

Comment: In Python3, the default string type is unicode, where as a `wb` file expects bytestrings.  So make sure you open the file in a mode that is compatible with `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: @ hpaulj I was triying a lot of time I added a final attempt that is failing for a strange character that is not maping well,  @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: Ok at some point you are going to need to split this into seperate questions instead of appending your trouble to the single thread.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen sorry I am going to make a new question with the new feedback and explain better the situation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your special character, in a Py3 Ipython session renders as:

```
In [31]:  '\U0001f609'
Out[31]: ''
```

Give us a small sample of the dictionary, or better yet the values that you use to build it.

I haven't worked with `csv` much, and `csv.DictWriter` even less.  `numpy` users often write `csv` files with `np.savetxt`.  That's easy to use when writing a purely numeric array.  If you want to write a mix of character and numeric columns, it is tricker, requiring the use of a structured array.

Another option is to simply write a text file directly.  Just open it, and use `f.write(...)` to write a formatted line to the file.  In fact `np.savetxt` does essentially that:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for row in myArray:
       f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

`savetxt` constructs a `fmt` string like `%s, %d, %f\n`.  It also works with bytestrings, requiring a `wb` mode.  And as such could have even more problems with your special character.

It might help to focus on printing your dictionary, one key at a time, e.g.

```
for k in mydict.keys():
   print(`%s, %s`%(k, mydict[k]))
```

for a start.  Once you get the `print` format right, it is easy to convert that to a file write.

===============

I can write a hypothetical dictionary with your code:

```
In [58]: adict={1:'\U0001f609'}
In [59]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    ...:     writer=csv.writer(f)
    ...:     for k,v in adict.items():
    ...:         writer.writerow([k,v])
    ...:         
In [60]: cat test.txt
1,
```

Comment: thanks this is breaking the generation of the csv file do you know how can I avoid this exeption?, thanks a lot for your support

Comment: thanks for the support I added more details of how is composed my dictionary if you need some other detail in order to help me please let me know thanks a lot to help me to overcome this situation

Answer (score 2):

The [`writerows` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) must take a list of dictionaries:

```
Out = open("dictionary.csv", "wb")
w = csv.DictWriter(Out,dict_clusters.keys())
w.writerows([dict_clusters])
Out.close()
```

You're probably looking for [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) which takes a single dictionary object:

```
Out = open("dictionary.csv", "wb")
w = csv.DictWriter(Out,dict_clusters.keys())
w.writerow(dict_clusters)
Out.close()
```

---

Aside: you might also want to consider using `open` as a context manager (in a `with` block) to ensure the file is properly closed:

```
with open("dictionary.csv", mode="wb") as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, headers=dict_clusters.keys())
    writer.writerow(dict_clusters)
```

Comment: @ Trey Hunner ,  I tried 3 times and I was not able to get the desired csv I am not sure what is happening, I would like to appreciate support, thanks a lot for the attention, my question is updated with the new attempts @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen,